# Fluentd is not able to send logs to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, fluentd

I have created the bucket policy and fluentd configuration to send files to s3 bucket but even though I donot see any error in the pod logs , fluentd is unable to send the logs to s3 bucket

I am attaching the bucket policy for my s3 bucket :-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1698058136671",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1698058112177",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
            "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ayushs3bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1698064596736",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ayushs3bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I am also attaching my fluentd config:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: default
data:
  fluent.conf: >
    <source>
     @type tail
     path "/path/in/container/*.log"
     tag "sample1.log"
     read_from_head true
     <parse>
      @type none
     </parse>
    </source>

     <match "sample1.log">
       @type file
       path "/path/in/container/test.log"
       compress gzip
       flush_interval 60s
     </match>

     <match sample1.log>
      @type s3
      aws_key_id EXAMPLEKEY
      aws_sec_key EXAMPLESECRET
      s3_bucket ayushs3bucket
      s3_region ap-northeast-1
      store_as gzip
      s3_object_key_format %{time_slice}/output_file.log
      path /path/to/your/output
      time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H
      time_slice_wait 1m
      utc
     </match>
```

Comment: You should immediately revoke your AWS access key.